# How to impliment MVC Authorization when older system is in place and returns a string

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authorization

I am not using any of **asp.net** Authentication in my code. It is handled by an outside library. I get back a success or failure from the function. So all the work is done for me.sCould I get some examples of how I would implement this in MVC3. I know a little, I have had 2 weeks experience.

Thanks.

```
  AuthFunction("UserName", "password");
```

Comment: I think this is how I would do it. If it comes back success then set FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(usernname,false). I am reading a book as I am asking this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement your own [MembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx). The [ValidateUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.validateuser%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method will use `AuthFunction` method from your library.

[This](http://www.danharman.net/2011/06/23/asp-net-mvc-3-custom-membership-provider-with-repository-injection/) tutorial should be good. Just skip the repository things because those are already implemented by your library. Carefully check the configuration section at the bottom of the tutorial.